# Having problems implementing Create User with FIRAuth

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've ran into this issue and have been trying to solve it for a few days now and it seems everything I try it creates more errors. I'm having problems creating a user with this function use FIRAuth and its telling me to add in a `;` right before in, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Picture of Errors:

[image: Picture of Errors]

```
func handleRegistration() {
        guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passTextField.text
            else {
                print("Form is not Valid")
                return
        }



        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: FIRUser?, error) in

         if error != nil {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

        print("Login Successful")
    }
```

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: you should watch this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html, explain how closures work, @Dravidian is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :-

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in

     if error != nil {
        print("Error")
        return
    }else{
        print("Login Successful")
        return 
   }
})
```

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer if it solved your issue :) Happy Coding.

Comment: That creates more errors :-/ 10 more to be exact. everything else I try seems to break my UIcolor(s) code including this fix :-/

Comment: I cannot say anything about other error's but i am definite of this as answer. :) Avoid fanning out  question in comments. Post another question or try to debug yourself